# How do I ignore a few rows below the header (including header) when sorting data in sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sorting, google-sheets-filter

I want to leave the filter buttons at the top, where they are but begin sorting from where the checkboxes are.. Every way I try, the filter buttons move or it sorts the top "notes" area which I want frozen.

[image: Example:]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]!   Take the site [Tour], review [ask], and search the tag [[tag:google-sheets]] on this site to see if there is anything that helps. *"I want to leave the filter buttons at the top"*  It isn't logical to use the Sheets filters to sort a range but then, expect part of the range that is being sorted, not sorted.  If I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do and there is a practical problem about Sheets we can assist with, please [edit] the question with additional details that clarify it so we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

One easy workaround would be to move the notes above the label row so that it is no longer part of the filtered area.

I do not think there is any turnkey way to keep notes where they are without making filtering way too complicated.